# xcode4 calculator code issues

Tags: xcode4

I'm trying to build a calulator that takes a user input number and divides by 3 different numbers, returning 3 different values, I have tried several variations of code but can't seem to get it working. Here is the code I have already written:

in the .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *userInput;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label3;
}

-(IBAction)calculate;
-(IBAction) hideKeyboard; 

@end
```

In the .m file

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)calculate {

    NSString *input = userInput.text;
    NSString *result1 = label1.text;
    NSString *result2 = label2.text;
    NSString *result3 = label3.text;

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int num4;

    num1 = [input intValue];
    num2 = [result1 400];
    num3 = [result2 2500];
    num4 = [result3 500];

    result1 = num1 / num2;
    result2 = num1 / num3;
    result3 = num1 / num4; 


    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", result1];
    label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", result2];
    label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", result3];
}

-(IBAction)hideKeyboard {
    [userInput resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: This looks dodgy: `num2 = [result1 400];`.  What is that?

Comment: What are you doing with `[result1 400]` `[result2 2500]` etc? That is not proper syntax